# Why BTsync does not sync contents of Symlinks?

Tags: ubuntu, btsync

Do in Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/haetex $HOME/BTsync/
```

See the file in connected device. You only see the symlink but not the actual content.

---

How can you share Contents of Symlinks in BTSync?

Comment: Did you try making a hard link instead of a soft link? A soft link is just a "file" - a hard link may solve this.

Comment: Is the hardlink the one which destroyes the original file if you delete it?

Comment: [Yes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50179/what-happens-when-you-delete-a-hard-link)

Comment: @Vince42 I think hardlink is the one which get deleted if all its links are destroyed. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://help.getsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/205504529-Soft-links-hard-links-and-symbolic-links) an answer about *Soft Links, Hard Links And Symbolic Links*

> Sync is able to synchronize symbolic links, however, the folders which are referenced to via these links (aka target folders) will NOT be synced. In order to get the target folders synchronized as well, they must be added to Sync.